# why separate navigation rule from code in MVC

Tags: ios, jsf, frameworks

more and more frameworks are trying to separate navigation rules from code. for example, JSF got "navigation-rule" tag in faces-config.xml to control page flows. new xcode 4.2 introduced storyboard so developers don't have to write code to handle navigation between scenes.
my question is why it's so important to separate navigation flow from code. what's wrong with writing code in controller to handle pages flow?

Comment: Note that JSF 2.0 has eliminated those verbose XML navigation rules by implicit navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head: having a navigation flow specified in a single place makes it easier to understand a codebase you're not familiar with – you can see exactly how you can get to a given view without having to hunt this down.

You mention the storyboard editor in XCode – another advantage would be that having the navigation structure as a first-class entity makes it toolable.

If your framework (maybe one of the umpty Java page flow frameworks?) also checks whether a user sticks to this flow, it's possible to easily catch errors that would happen if the intended flow is violated. (E.g. if the user tries to open the middle of a "wizard" type interaction.)

Using such a framework imposes a cognitive overhead compared to "straightforward" code. That doesn't mean you should ignore patterns at abstraction levels higher than "controller method code", or you'll turn straightforward code into spaghetti code. Obviously the benefit of formalising your navigation flow increases with the number of views in your app and the complexity of the connections between them.